# Memory Leak using libcurl C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, libcurl

In my C program I try to download a file using libcurl. I am running OS X 10.9.3 and I have linked my program to libcurl.dylib. Everything works fine when I try to download the file, but memory leaks and the program keeps taking up more memory ever time I use libcurl.

I have tested in many times and I have cut out other portions of code to find out that libcurl is the only part of my program that is leaking.

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
 }

/* Function leaks memory! */
void download_file(char* url, char* filename){
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    const char *homedir = pw->pw_dir;
    char filePath[FILENAME_MAX];

    strcpy(filePath, homedir);
    strcat(filePath, "/");
    strcat(filePath, filename);
    FILE *fp;
    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl){
        remove(filePath);
        fp = fopen(filePath, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup(); // Tried to add this.
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

}

Unfortunately, there are not many others ways to download a file (unless I rewrite the HTTP protocol) and keep my code portable to both Linux and Mac systems.

Comment: Could you share how did you determine that your program is leaking memory?.  Valgrind would be pretty useful as your program runs on Linux as well.

Comment: Yes even with a curl_easy_cleanup it leaks memory. Also I put this function in a while loop and watch the memory grow as the program continues.